# Nginx : redirect httpS://....com:8080/ simply to httpS://....com

Tags: linux, ssl, nginx, web, redirect

I am trying to redirect http traffic to https (classic case, I know).

**But**, my issue is that before we moved on to serving over https, we had the site serving on `http://poubelle.net:8080/`. The problem is that even though we are now asking all users to use `https://poubelle.net/`, every now and then a user will type `httpS://poubelle.net:8080` and that fails.

I have tried *many* combinations and solutions, including `erro_page 497` type solutions, but I need help to solve this.

Below is my current simplified config... what do I need to add to make it so that:

1. http://poubelle.net/
2. http://poubelle.net:8080/
3. httpS://poubelle.net:8080/
4. and of course https://poubelle.net/

all redirect to https://poubelle.net/ ?  (config below works for cases 1, 2 and 4 but not 3)

---

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name ${SERVER_NAME};
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name ${SERVER_NAME};
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ${SERVER_NAME};
    ssl_certificate .../fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key .../privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate .../cert.pem;
    ...


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        ...
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /data/nginx/html/poubelle.net;
        ...
    }


}
```

Comment: `http` and `https` services on the same domain are divided by port number. It's just that the port 80 and 443 can be omitted because they are the respective defaults. The service on port 8080 can **only be one of** `http` or `https` - never both!!

Comment: @RichardSmith: Yes I agree & understand, but I've seen some config that looked like:
`listen 8080 ssl` which makes me believe it would be possible to instruct Nginx to listen/manage/redirect crypted `SSL` (https) traffic coming in on port 8080. Hence my question above, as my attempts and trials have thus far been unsuccessful.

Comment: You can enable SSL on any port. If you enable SSL on port 8080, your (3) would work, but your (2) would stop working.

Comment: Right, makes sense of course and it is what I surmised initially actually, but thank you @RichardSmith for confirming.